# Apache Ignite - how to enable HTTPS Rest API

Tags: https, ignite

This works (http):
    http://ip-address:port/ignite?cmd=version

This does not (httpS):
    https://ip-address:port/ignite?cmd=version

How to enable httpS for Ignite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST API is based on Jetty server, so you need to configure SSL connector and certificates. Please refer [1, 2] for details.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#general-configuration
[2] https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL