# Monitoring Apache Ignite performance by GridGain web console

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am using Apache Ignite 2.8.0. I have enabled HTTPS for REST API by following,

```
<New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
<Set name="keyStorePath">C:\\JAYAPRAKASH\\softwares\\ignite\\apache-ignite-2.8.0-bin\\keystore.jks</Set>
<Set name="keyStorePassword">1234567</Set>
<Set name="keyManagerPassword">1234567</Set>
<Set name="trustStorePath">C:\\JAYAPRAKASH\\softwares\\ignite\\apache-ignite-2.8.0-bin\\trust.jks</Set>
<Set name="trustStorePassword">123456</Set>
</New>
```

Now I am starting my web agent by following configuration,

```
tokens=adba082b-6b3f-46b5-bcf0-886e5571da4e
node-uri=https://localhost:8080
server-key-store=C:\\JAYAPRAKASH\\softwares\\ignite\\apache-ignite-2.8.0-bin\\keystore.jks
server-key-store-password=1234567
server-trust-store=C:\\JAYAPRAKASH\\softwares\\ignite\\apache-ignite-2.8.0-bin\\trust.jks
server-trust-store-password=123456
```

it gives the following output in command line,

```
[2020-05-19T09:24:19,457][INFO ][http-client-18][WebSocketRouter] Successfully completes handshake with server
[2020-05-19T09:24:19,616][ERROR][pool-2-thread-1][ClusterHandler] Failed execute request on node 
[url=https://localhost:8080, parameters={cmd=top, attr=true, mtr=false, caches=false}]
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path 
to requested target
```

How do I connect my GriGain Web Console with Ignite cluster when HTTPS is enabled for REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm not sure that your Ignite REST is actually HTTPS. You need to configure that separately: [Apache Ignite - how to enable HTTPS Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981117/apache-ignite-how-to-enable-https-rest-api)
2. Looks like your certficate is not signed by your trust store? Can you dump details of your trust and keystore?

Comment: try `keytool -list -v keystore <foo.jks>`

Comment: I am new to this SSL concept. can you please give step by step process?

Comment: Try https://medium.com/vividcode/enable-https-support-with-self-signed-certificate-for-embedded-jetty-9-d3a86f83e9d9

Comment: the same output i got

Comment: I think you did not configure your HTTPS client correctly, that's out of scope of Apache Ignite.

Comment: @BalajiG this security configuration guide explicates how to configure SSL/TLS for the client and server end as well as WebConsole: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/tutorials/security/ssl-guide

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Security Guide that covers in details how to enable SSL/TLS for Ignite client, servers and WebConsole: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/tutorials/security/ssl-guide